# iOS App allowing news users to sign up for free accounts

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We are a website based service.  We do not charge for accounts.  We charge for services the user selects to do (such as exporting data).  We collect money through our website and store that as credits in our system.

We have built a free app app and have been updating the app.

We would like to provide a user sign up in our app.  We are having troubles figuring out if Apple will take issue with that.  We understand if we sign up a new account in the app, Apple will take a 30% cut (ala Spotify).

The question is how do they handle free accounts?

EDIT:

Our app currently lets the user charge for services against their current credit balance (such as exporting a file) and have not had an issue with that in 4 years we have been doing it.

EDIT 2:

At one point, they did reject our App for hot linking to our website.  That was 3 years ago and I forget if it was because they could create a new accout or could add credits to their account.  I can't find a way to go back and look up the rejection notification.

Comment: It depends on whether the payment is for tangible or intangible goods/services. All sales of intangible goods (e.g. game credits, music, books, premium apps and upgrades) are required to use App Store payment, and thus incur the 30% fee to Apple.

Sales of tangible goods and services on the other hand, are exempt (and I believe disallowed) from using App Store payments. Companies like Airbnb and Uber have to rely on their own payment providers to collect payments from users. Therefore, they simply pay a fee to their payment provider (Braintree, Stripe, PayPal etc.), and not the 30% to Apple.

Comment: Yep, we understand that completely.  But will they take 30% of $0 for a new free user account?  Our app currently lets the user charge for services against their current credit balance and have not had an issue with that in 4 years we have been doing it.

Comment: No, they won't charge you then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not Apple customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0):

Accounts are unrelated to purchases. Purchases and accounts are often used together, but this is a convenience and not strict requirement.

In your case:

1. The user may access the app with an account.
2. No payment is asked for the account.
3. Through this account, the user may receive content which has been paid for by credit card.
4. Credit card details have been submitted through your web site.

This is ok, as long as you do not take credit card payments in the app, or provide any buttons or links to credit card payments, from in the app.

According to the [App Store Review guide](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

> 3.1.1 In-App Purchase: If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game
>   currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a
>   full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not include
>   buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct
>   customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP. Any credits or
>   in-game currencies purchased via IAP must be consumed within the app
>   and may not expire, and you should make sure you have a restore
>   mechanism for any restorable in-app purchases. Please remember to
>   assign the correct purchasability type or your app will be rejected.
>   Apps should not directly or indirectly enable gifting of IAP content,
>   features, or consumable items to others. Apps distributed via the Mac
>   App Store may host plug-ins or extensions that are enabled with
>   mechanisms other than the App Store.

And

> 3.1.3 Content-based “Reader” Apps: Apps may allow a user to access previously purchased content or subscriptions (specifically:
>   magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video, access to
>   professional databases, VoIP, cloud storage, and approved services
>   such as educational apps that manage student grades and schedules),
>   provided the app does not direct users to a purchasing mechanism other
>   than IAP.

In other words, users may access content that has been paid for outside of the app.

If the user is directed by the app to pay for something, then you may not use external payment services, and you must use In App Purchase.

So, hot linking to your web site from your app to accept payments is not allowed, whereas downloading content which has already been paid for through your web site outside of the app is allowed.

If in doubt, contact Apple directly through their [support form](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs), or the [Apple developer program technical support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/technical/).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see where you answer my question.  How will Apple view letting a user sign up for a free account in the app?  If you are replying to them making purchases against their already paid for credits, our app does not allow users to add credits (credits that are used outside of the app).  They are using their already paid for credits which were bought from our website or over the phone.

Comment: I see the issue, I never explicitly mentioned your use case, I assumed it could be inferred. Accounts and purchases are not related to each other at all.

Comment: I have read over the the Review guide a few times and still left questions, hence the question posted here.  I am hoping to get other people's interpretation of the guidelines and I appreciate yours, thank you.

Comment: I expect the only way you are going to get a canonical answer, is if you get a response directly from someone at Apple, either to your question here, or if you contact them. It is otherwise unclear what kind of answer you are looking for. The best anyone outside of Apple can do technically is refer you to the documentation. You might also try the Apple developer forums.